# How do I get the full request details from WebException? (GET|POST etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api, system.net.webexception

I have an asp.net web api project. In my controllers I have set up the

```
ExceptionFilterAttribute
```

To catch any errors at a global level. There are two get requests being fired off from the controller method. They are failing and so I am seeing the exception being raised in the exception filter. However the exception is not showing me details of the failed request. Is it possible to get them? For example 4 GET requests might have been invoked and one of them is failing and the exception is being thrown. But all im seeing is a message saying...

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'xx.xx.com'

But I need more details, like the query string etc...

The response object on the web exception is null too :-(

Answer (score 0):

Within the `OnException` method of your `ExceptionFilterAttribute` you have a parameter argument of type `HttpActionExecutedContext`. Within the instance of this class you can access the `Request` and `Response` properties to get all the information you need, either of the request or the response. Within the `ActionContext` property you can even get all routing, controller and action informations.

```
var requestHttpMethod = actionExecutedContext.Request.Method;
var requestUri = actionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri;

var controllerDescriptor = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor;
var actionDescriptor = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor;
```

You can also modify the response object to return a more appropriated error message. Just look around a bit what information these classes can provide you.